# Blocking deciphering py.exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, exe

You know that a python file converted to an exe file can be deciphered and its codes can be displayed.
What is the way to prevent this decryption event? I don't want to people see the codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Nuitka** to convert .py file into a C-based standalone executable. Then, pass a resulting .exe file through **VMProtect** to obfuscate the binaries.